# change css dynamically by selecting dropdown list item

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have the following Dropdownlist with yes or no options-:`

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlchangecss" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="yes">yes</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="no"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

i want to add a css dynamically like that-:

```
.imgFullWidth {
    width: 100%; 
    height: auto; 
    float: left; 
    margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}
```

when I select yes option in Dropdownlist.
How can i do this?

Comment: To which element you want to do so? and have you tried anything?

Comment: Whatever your point is, I am sure there's alot of duplicated questions around. Try hard more pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a working example for you. You can find [the jsfiddle in here](https://jsfiddle.net/q13c9faf/)

This piece of code uses JQuery. (Remember, for these type of tasks, JQuery is your friend =] ).

**HTML**

```
<select id="dropDownMenu">
    <option value="option1" selected="selected">yes</option>
    <option value="option2">no</option>
  </select>
<br>
<img id="picture" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f5/House_Sparrow_mar08.jpg/220px-House_Sparrow_mar08.jpg">
```

**Javascript**

```
function changeStyle(){
    $('#picture').addClass('imgFullWidth');
}

$('#dropDownMenu').change(changeStyle);
```

I used your CSS so there is no change there.